# DynaTree adding [...] in the large nodes

Tags: javascript, json, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I have dynatree that is working with my MVC4 WebApplcation. It gets data from controller in JSON format. Node usually has about 2'000 or 3'000 and more items. It takes several seconds to load this tree. Is there any way to show 5 items in the begining and 5 items from the end and between them to show[...]. Thank you.

Comment: I have one way to solve this problem, but it's not rather good. Solving is in extracting fixed number of items from DB (on the server side) and then generate manually json response on the server side and send it to client. But this way has low perfomance.

Comment: Did you check lazy loading feature of dynatree ?

Comment: Yes, I have checked lazy loading of dynatree. It's function of loading ALL items in node on its activating. But I need to load only five-ten items in the begining and the same number of items in the end. I want to see [...] between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply only generate those 21 nodes on the server (i.e. 10 first, 10 last and one special node with `title: '[...]', isPlaceholder: true`.
This would cause only 21 nodes to be displayed.

In the activate handler you could then check for `node.data.isPlaceholder` and do a complete reload if the user clicks '[...]'.